# MongoDB is not running as service

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I have installed Mongo on my OSX

```
$ brew info mongodb
mongodb: stable 4.0.2 (bottled)
...
```

I'm starting MongoDB service by this command:

```
$ brew services start mongodb
```

I can observe the status of mongodb:

```
$ brew services list
Name    Status  User  Plist
mongodb started megas /Users/megas/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
...
```

But when I'm running mongo client it give me an error:

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.2
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2018-09-19T15:18:22.490+0300 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

When I manually start `mongod` then it works as it should be.

What I'm missing here?

Update:
If I run it manually it throughs message and stops

```
$ mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
2018-09-19T21:47:51.531+0300 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling 
TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'

$ cat /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf
# Store data in /usr/local/var/mongodb instead of the default /data/db
dbpath = /usr/local/var/mongodb

# Append logs to /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logpath = /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
logappend = true

# Only accept local connections
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Do you use the same config starting as a service and starting manually?

Comment: I just ran `mongod` and connecting to it by `mongo` so I think there's same config

Comment: Can you confirm it? What config is used in `/Users/megas/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist`? can you start mongo manually using this config (--config /path option)?

Comment: @AlexBlex Hm, I can't run it manually, pls see the update

Comment: What's in the config?

Comment: The mongod is different from `which mongod`, it should point to the same command, isn't it?

Comment: Not necessarily. The one in your path can be a symlink. We need to examine what's in the mongodb config mongod.conf, not the plist.

Comment: @AlexBlex In mongod.conf dbpath =  /usr/local/var/mongodb, the default points to /data/db.

Comment: Weird. The config is exactly like mine, and I have exactly the same output when I start `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf`, but it works - there is `I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017` in /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log and I can connect to the db from another console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180431/discussion-between-alex-blex-and-megas).